# Stored procedure with encrypt always returns null

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote this stored procedure to encrypt a value, but it always returns `Null`

What am I doing wrong here?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `scramble`(`enc_mode` VARCHAR(7), `enc_id` INT, `enc_str` VARCHAR(2400))
    RETURNS varchar(2400)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
declare enc_mode varchar(7);
declare enc_id int(10);
declare enc_str varchar(2400);
declare enc_output varchar(2400);

if enc_mode = 'encrypt' then
set enc_output = lower(hex(aes_encrypt('enc_id','x')));
elseif enc_mode = 'decrypt' then
set enc_output = aes_decrypt(unhex(enc_str),'x');
else
set enc_output = 'Arrg!';
end if;

return enc_output;

END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't re-declare

```
declare enc_mode varchar(7);
declare enc_id int(10);
declare enc_str varchar(2400);
```

Use enc_mode,enc_id and enc_str directly in your logic